# Typescript typing event subscriber, compare types of the same function

Tags: typescript, function, types

I'm currently working on eventSubscriber implementation.

```js
eventSubscriber(
  functions => [
    { event: UserRegisteredEvent, function: functions.sendEmail },
    { event: UserRegisteredEvent, function: functions.sendSMS },
  ],
  {
    sendEmail: async event => {},
    sendSMS: async event => {},
  },
);
```

First argument (returning subscribers) is taking second as parameter, this way I can explicitly reference function from within subscribers (and ctrl+click is redirecting to implementation).

Second argument is a object of functions, after you attached function to the event, function paramter type should be automatically inferred from event.

Event is a class with a `payload` property available in prototype.

```js
class UserRegisteredEvent {
  constructor(public payload: { userId: string; date: string }) {}
}
```

My current solution have a bug which makes all events to be passed to function parameters as union.

```js
eventSubscriber(
  functions => [
    { event: UserRegisteredEvent, function: functions.sendEmail },
    { event: UserUnregisteredEvent, function: functions.sendSMS },
  ],
  {
    sendEmail: async event => {}, // event is equal to 'UserRegisteredEvent | UserUnregisteredEvent' instead of 'UserRegisteredEvent'
    sendSMS: async event => {}, // event is equal to 'UserRegisteredEvent | UserUnregisteredEvent' instead of 'UserUnregisteredEvent'
  },
);
```

[image]

Below are my current typings for eventSubscriver function.

```js
const eventSubscriber = <
  TFunctions extends { [key in string]: (event: any) => Promise<void> },
  TSubscriptions extends {
    event: { name: string; prototype: { payload: any } };
    function: TFunctions[keyof TFunctions];
  }
>(
  subscriptions: (functions: TFunctions) => TSubscriptions[],
  functions: {
    [key in keyof TFunctions]: (
      event: TSubscriptions["function"] extends TFunctions[key]
        ? TSubscriptions["event"] extends infer UEvent
          ? UEvent extends any
            ? UEvent
            : never
          : never
        : never,
    ) => Promise<void>;
  },
) => {
//...
};
```

As far as I understand problem is with `event: TSubscriptions["function"] extends TFunctions[key]` since it's the same as `event: Function extends Function`.
Ternary mentioned above is always resulting `true` since every Function extends every Function.

Is it possible to compare function more strictly or maybe do some other workaround?

I would really appropriate any help.

[Fully reproductable example in typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOAlBBzAlhALshAJgKIBuCAdjtAN4CwAUNNMAPbm5ICuwOLSAFAAdOAIxCZg0QWACeIFmAIAuGtE6IkASWXQOmcugDc0AmDwq9B6AF8AlDWsNH9UJBjxksckgzY8P4jJKGgYmVnYcLh4+IVFxSWk5BR1qNQ1tC0j9I2gfSDZMpGybe2pnZwZw3GgEIJwAZVEIYCKRZGgAXmgAHlDoABUAMU5yHkw2GAQADzxyAhhUgG0AawQZaH1dLIMAXRV+WoocFTByGXsOgD5oAAUkFgBbbARukhZMAmvrABo+-saRM0ioIcON2DUZhR5iFGEwanUVKlyGAHghCtljIJ7rwcDJBGjVIl5IoTmcbDZDH0mAAzEZjAoDYajUETFZrFjUxl0lnsHaU2HOS78PoQJotTAgsEQfa05lSlRDblSi7Xf5i4E8iCLHa-WGy+nsRFU6Bs9abVYyDlcuUTPbQYWwuHwo4KgFAiWaxYAIn1PK9Owhs2hipt7FNO2NToA-AM3eLJayvYdKP7A1CYPpqe1YKQjpGndAYzm6mm5jBTjJ8wXC3Bc5QqwWVORDkgG0wmy2Gx2yEhdU6Vbd7k9EK93p9+UwfgwB3RYQB6OcAOmXTn5DGTDXVmDaAj6vqlnWui2NqQ3Kg8qF8uHwgSO32g+4Zj-Yi8QcyIDzAmBANj7cNPCJwBoaBYNeAR1jg97Pioz4QK+UL1AAsvUv59DqfSzk6b7EJ+34nBAMijM6wRXA494LtALDLMa2FIfU+GEZIG6HmR0AUVRfRTvQthrvQG5xq0yAOjSSoTCxx6OqoZ5AcgIF+DeEFQaJ5AwcpcHYR+X4-lxToAS6MlIF4Pigf4hCKQ+ymqaG6kIchqGwuhsKYXCGm4SADFEcxpFlORc66AAFiwnAgAQ0BtNAAAGuL4laF5yWBZl1BFNG2fR0CQIxxFUN5PxsX5ECBcFoXhVFeIILFGhGVepm3pQyUCrqPEMOudQCduQl7mp4knll57AdVCl1EpoZWQaNnvm59m6b1BlVSZg13hZI1LWN8ETVpU3QI5TDOUwrlaR5TEljlvmUdRkm0chh1ZSxPl5QFQUhWFCDQM2PacY1-JAA)

```js
class UserRegisteredEvent {
  constructor(public payload: { userId: string; date: string }) {}
}
class UserUnregisteredEvent {
  constructor(public payload: { userId: string; reason: string }) {}
}

const eventSubscriber = <
  TFunctions extends { [key in string]: (event: any) => Promise<void> },
  TSubscriptions extends {
    event: { name: string; prototype: { payload: any } };
    function: TFunctions[keyof TFunctions];
  }
>(
  subscriptions: (functions: TFunctions) => TSubscriptions[],
  functions: {
    [key in keyof TFunctions]: (
      event: TSubscriptions["function"] extends TFunctions[key]
        ? TSubscriptions["event"] extends infer UEvent
          ? UEvent extends any
            ? UEvent
            : never
          : never
        : never,
    ) => Promise<void>;
  },
) => {
  //...
};

eventSubscriber(
  functions => [
    { event: UserRegisteredEvent, function: functions.sendEmail },
    { event: UserRegisteredEvent, function: functions.sendSMS },
  ],
  {
    sendEmail: async event => {}, // ok
    sendSMS: async event => {}, // ok
  },
);

eventSubscriber(
  functions => [
    { event: UserRegisteredEvent, function: functions.sendEmail },
    { event: UserUnregisteredEvent, function: functions.sendSMS },
  ],
  {
    sendEmail: async event => {}, // should be `typeof UserRegisteredEvent`
    sendSMS: async event => {}, // should be `typeof UserUnregisteredEvent`
  },
);

eventSubscriber(
  functions => [
    { event: UserRegisteredEvent, function: functions.sendEmail },
    { event: UserUnregisteredEvent, function: functions.sendEmail },
  ],
  {
    sendEmail: async event => {}, // ok
    sendSMS: async event => {}, // should be never
  },
);
```

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code here to be a [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue if we paste it into our own IDEs.  The snippet at the top seems to refer to an undeclared `UserRegisteredEvent` value, and the snippet at the bottom has no immediately obvious attention-drawing problem.  It would be easier to get started if the issue were evident from the example code.

Comment: (Note, please test your code in a standalone IDE to make sure you have included all the relevant definitions and have not made any typos or syntax errors.)

Comment: See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6xD0m) for context.  I don't think there's any good way to get inference working well with `eventSubscriber` as written; it's too circular.  The typings are expressible but it's not inferred properly.  Maybe refactoring to the `eventSubscriberRefactored` version would work for you?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?